# Hibernate get result group by name sum of account in separate list class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class as following

```
class Account{
    int id;
    String name;
    ACType actype;
    double amount;
}

enum ACType{
    CREDIT,DEBIT
}
```

Now Suppose I have a table as following

```
1 name1 CREDIT 10
2 name1 CREDIT 20
3 name1 DEBIT 10
4 name2 CREDIT 10
5 name2 DEBIT 10
6 name2 DEBIT 30
```

Now I want the summation of each name

```
name1 CREDIT -20
name2 DEBIT 30
```

I dont have any class matching this signature

How can i get this result in a list and access them??

I am using `Hibernate Criteria` and the above class is `JPA` annotated
So what would be the `Criteria`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create class

```
class Test{
    String name;
    double amount;

    // getter 
    // setter
}
```

write query as following

```
@Transactional
public List<Test> getAccountDetailsBalanceSheet(){
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). 
        createSQLQuery("SELECT name, SUM( CASE WHEN actype =  DEBIT THEN amount ELSE amount * -1 END ) AS amount FROM Account GROUP BY name")
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Test.class));
    return (List<Test>) query.list();
}
```

you can get `DEBIT` or `CREDIT` by iterating through loop and put a condition whether amount positive or negative to get the final result